# How to display an error message on react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, routes

The following code Is used as an input receiver from the user of an excel file, and if the excel file is in the right format, it will take it to MAINPAGE.
 but, here's the trick, When inputting a false formatted excel file (xlsx) I want to display an error message (Pop up Or even an alert), And i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

I tried tooltip but its unrelated to the issue, And I tried an alert but that didn't work, not speaking about the looks of it which was extremely bad looking.:

```
function App() {

  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<any>();

  const handleFileData = (data: any) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < data[0].length; index++) {
      if (data[0][index] != null) {
        if (data[0][index].includes("name" && "id")) {
          setFileData(data);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  const isData = () => {
    if (fileData !== undefined) {
      return <MainPage Data={fileData}></MainPage>;
    }
    return HOMEPAGE

  }

  const HOMEPAGE = (
    <div className="App" style={{ "overflowX": "hidden", }}>
      <h1 style={{ "marginBottom": "50px", "marginTop": "25px" }}>NEXUM Interface</h1>
      <InputPart handleFileData={handleFileData}></InputPart>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={HOMEPAGE}></Route>
        <Route path="/main" element={isData()}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**If u have an advice for me or can format the code for it to display an error message in case of an error (Look at isData, currently I'm returning the HOMEPAGE, I want to return the HOMEPAGE with an error message) It will help alot.**

Comment: Help please? Maybe just an idea?

Comment: maybe you can add one more prop in the MainPage component and handle the error condition. If the errorProp is set show error message else show file content.

Comment: Interesting take my friend, i'll try.